# CORS 401 OPTIONS error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

There is a problem with CORS preflight request.

I have tried both `config.EnableCors();` + `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]` on the controller and `app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

and I was getting the following error

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49871' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401

To solve that I stoped using the above methods and edited my webconfig as in the picture. This solved the problem but created another one. Please look at the pic (you will have to zoom)

Note: I dont have a global.asax to add begin application request method. Is there a simple way to solve this? Why nothing works ?? :(

[image]

```
 <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<authentication mode="None" />
<authorization>
  <allow verbs="OPTIONS" users="*"/>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Have you enabled Windows authentication on this site?

Comment: @LexLi I have added part of the web.config.  My application is an angularjs calling a web api. This API uses token authentication

Comment: The preflight request is anonymous without any token or credentials. Thus, it is very likely the authentication method you use that blocks it with 401 response. You might further analyze, and this blog post might give you some hints, https://blog.lextudio.com/2014/11/how-to-handle-cors-preflight-requests-in-asp-net-mvcweb-api-with-windows-authentication/